# How to create CSS-based (big) quotation marks?

Tags: css

I want something like this: http://img257.imageshack.us/img257/5906/globalcolleage.png
I know how to create CSS-image-based bullets, but for quotations I can't figure out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[An example](http://24ways.org/2005/swooshy-curly-quotes-without-images)
[another nice one](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/06/12/block-quotes-and-pull-quotes-examples-and-good-practices/) See under

[image]
Gallery of Pull Quotes and Citations

:)

Answer (score 0):

you can setup a internal division with small text size and set a big font size for the division or similar for the quotes